# Best way to manage services in Knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js

What is the best way to manage services in knockout.js?

Comment: I think you need to be a _little bit_ more specific in your question. What exactly are you looking to achieve?

Comment: What is the Way to use WebAPI with Knockout.js within same page? can you share best example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use jQuery's `ajax()` method.

As for *when*, you have two options:

1. Add a subscription to an observable whose value you wish to save.
   For example,

   ```
   var viewModel = function() {

       var self = this;

       self.name = ko.observable("");
       self.name.subscribe(function(latestValue) {
           // This subscription will be triggered each time
           // the 'name' observable is updated.
           // The latest value of the observable is passed 
           // here as a parameter.
           $.ajax({
               // see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for details
           });
       });
   }
   ```
2. Create a `save` function, then invoke this from the DOM / view

   ```
   var viewModel = function() {

       var self = this;

       self.name = ko.observable("");

       self.save = function() {
           // unlike the first example, you would typically
           // POST more data in this AJAX request
           $.ajax({
               // see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for details
           });
       };
   }
   ```

   And then in your DOM / view

   ```
   <input type="button" value="Save" data-bind="click: save" />
   ```

When using the second example you'll probably find it easiest to POST data as JSON, and in such a case you would probably expect to use `ko.toJSON` or even `JSON.stringify`. However, I'd recommend that you define your own `toJSON` function on your view-model.

The reason for suggesting that you define your own `toJSON` function is that your view-model may have members that you either don't *want* or don't *need* to send back to the server (a selectable list of countries, for example, or computed observables). If you call `ko.toJSON` then everything will be serialised; if you define your own function then you can control exactly what data is serialised.

Furthermore, `JSON.stringify` (which Knockout calls internally) looks on your objects for a `toJSON` function. If present, this function is used, otherwise it serialises everything.

An important point here is that your `toJSON` function should return *an object which is to be serialised, not the serialised JSON itself*.
[[Documentation]](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html)

So we'll modify example 2 (from above):

```
var viewModel = function() {

    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable("");

    self.save = function() {
        // unlike the first example, you would typically
        // POST more data in this AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            // see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for details
        });
    };

    self.toJSON = function() {
        return {
            name: ko.unwrap(self.name),
            ...
        };
    };
}
```